# Inquiry on Dax formula on COUNTROWS or SUM for aggregation

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to calculate the total number of student enrolled to each service provider but I do not want the same student counted double if they have enrolled difference course with the same company. Below is the sample data:

| Service Provider | Course | Student name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| company A | C1 | Jane |
| company A | C4 | Cherry |
| company A | C4 | Jane |
| company A | C8 | Kethna |
| company B | C2 | Mic |
| company C | C5 | Jane |

I tried to use COUNTROWS but it only take 1 variable that is the table name. Using SUM or SUMX is also not possible due to not numerical value for each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Measure =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[Student name] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[Service Provider] )
)
```

[image: Solution]